# Loop in T-SQL, how get field value

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

In an SQL Server 2005 database, I have a stored procedure. I get some date in put them in a temp table. I'd like loop in this temp table and depending of the value of some fields change the value of others and make some check. I have to do this for each row.

How can I do this ?

thanks,

UPDATE1

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    --Create temp table
    CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable(
        id      int IDENTITY(1, 1),
        PriceMax    int,
        PriceMin    int
    )

    -- Insert in temp table
    INSERT INTO #tmpReconciliation (PriceMax, PriceMin) 
        SELECT  PriceMax    = PriceMaxProduct,
                PriceMin    = PriceMinProduct
        FROM    Products

    DECLARE @RowNum int
    SELECT  @RowNum = Count(*) From #MyTempTable 
    WHILE @RowNum > 0                          
    BEGIN   

        if(....)
            PriceMin = 0
                 ....

    END

    --Drop temp table
    DROP TABLE #MyTempTable

END
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: A loop/while/cursor is *probably* not necessary. If you elaborate and post some code, we'll likely give you a set-based statement to do what you need.

Comment: Please go see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71633/how-should-newbies-ask-sql-questions then edit your question.

Comment: @Kris-I Brad's right, tell us the conditions of your checks and what you need to update, and you probably will be able to do your updates without the need of a cursor.

Comment: @LaGrandMere I need something working sure.... I don't like T-SQL, I'm a C# guys :)

Comment: @Kris-I : can you give us the part : if(....) PriceMin = 0 .... in pseudo code ? With it we'll be able to help you ... And IMHO, T-SQL's should become a friend of yours because sometimes it's really useful :)

Answer (score 2):

I read MSDN documentation for [WHILE loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx) and [CURSOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms180169.aspx).

For example, let's imagine your temp table is named Employee :

```
DECLARE @Emp_id int

DECLARE Employee_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT EmployeeID 
FROM Employee;

OPEN Employee_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor INTO @Emp_id;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      -- Here your actions
      PRINT @Emp_id
      FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor INTO @Emp_id;
   END;
CLOSE Employee_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Employee_Cursor;
GO
```

Here I decided to print EmployeeId, but everything is possible.

Tell us what are your checks, and what your temp table looks like if you need more help.

Comment: +! for good links and a good example.  I would like to reiterate @Brad's comment above that you very likely don't need to iterate over the values with a cursor.

Comment: @wcm yes, both @Brad and you are right. Let's wait to see @Kris-I update of his needs.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a cursor and inside the cursor run an update statement??

Cursors: http://www.jackdonnell.com/articles/SQL_CURSOR.htm